# Build never ends

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

maybe you have now the experience, bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package not ends to build the package, it says there are n actions but the number increases every time and it never stops the build

I want to create the tensorflow-package builder with command bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bodxx.png)

Comment: Are you following the same steps mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#build_and_install_the_pip_package). What does the verbose logs says?

Answer (score 0):

> the number increases every time and it never stops the build

This is typical bazel behavior, because bazel discovers all the commands necessary to run the build [lazily](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3582#issuecomment-329405311) (while the build is running, instead of before the build starts).

As long as commands are still finishing and new commands are being started, the build is making progress - let it continue and it should finish eventually.